# Is Cholesky factor of symmetric positive definite matrix unique?

Tags: linear-algebra

The Cholesky decomposition of a symmetric positive definite matrix $K$ is  $K=A^{T}A$, where the matrix $A$ is upper triangular and has positive diagonal entries. Is such a matrix $A$ unique?

If such a matrix $A$ is unique, then how to prove this uniqueness?

If such a matrix $A$ is not unique, please support an example.

Thank you !

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Statement) gives three references about the uniqueness of the decomposition. The proof is not straightforward, AFAIK.